# Showing that $A \subseteq B$ for $A=\{6t\mid t \in \mathrm Z\}$ and $B=\{3t\mid t \in \mathrm Z\}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

Let $A=\{6t\mid t \in \mathrm Z\}$, and $B=\{3t\mid t \in \mathrm Z\}$.

Then, show $A$ is a subset of $B$ and prove or disprove that $A = B$.

I already know that $A \neq B$, for I can pick a particular element in $B$ and show it isn't in $A$. But, to show $A \subseteq B$, can I say that $A$ is a subset of $B$ because every element of $A$ is also an element in $B$?

Comment: "can I say that $A$ is a subset of $B$ because every element of $A$ is also an element in $B$?" <-- this is precisely the definition of the statement "$A \subseteq B$". So, yes.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. You can argue that every element in $A$ is an element of $B$:

For every element $a = 6t \in A$, where $t\in \mathbb Z$, we have $a = 3(2t)$, and $2t\in \mathbb Z$ since $t\in \mathbb Z$, so by definition, $a \in B$.

Another way to summarize the above is to note that $A$ contains all and only even multiples of $3$, whereas $B$ contains *all* integer multiples of $3$, even and odd.

Hence $A\subseteq B$.

And just as you argued, it is clear $A\neq B$ because, e.g., any odd multiple of $3$ is clearly in $B$, but not in $A$, whose elements are strictly *even* multiples of $3$.